# I2C slave not ACK'ing quickly enough

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, timing

I am programming a microcontroller to talk with a slave device via I2C.  My I2C transactions always get NACK'd, but I believe the slave *is* ACK'ing the transaction, just a little bit too late and my microcontroller thinks it's a NACK.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is a trace of the transaction.

[image: I2c Trace]

The slave drives SDA low at the end to ACK the transaction.  But my I2C library always reports it a NACK.  Further more, the slave *keeps* SDA low since their isn't a 9th clock pulse, and my I2C peripheral gets stuck trying to finish the stop condition.

My I2C library is a reliable one from manufacturer that I've used many times successfully with different devices.  I'm thinking the slave is just a bit too slow with the ACK.

The current trace is at 100 KHz but I've tried at 10KHz and it does the same thing.  Any suggestions to solve this?

**More details**:

- slave: AMS AS3955
- master: Silicon labs EFM32 Pearl

**Update**

I bit banged the I2C operation in question and added the 9th clock cycle.  The same problem occurs.  After the operation, I disconnect SDA and measure it on the microcontroller side and slave side.  Micro-SDA is high (correct) but slave-SDA is pulled low still.  So it seems this may be more of an issue with the slave device than an I2C issue, right?

[image]

**Update 2**

See my posted answer.

Comment: It looks like your host is misbehaving. Even if a slave is slow, your host should register some condition, ACK or NACK, it shouldn't have any effect on the end of packet. The slave can't remove the ACK because there must be another "LOW" phase of the clock, which is not coming from your host.

Comment: What is the slave?

Comment: Is this a slave you've used before? It should generate the ACK on the ninth falling edge of the clock, but it appears to be waiting until the subsequent rising edge. Since it happens at any speed, it isn't a simple timing issue.

Comment: BTW, there *are* nine clock pulses -- since the idle state of the clock is high, you need to count the number of times it goes low, and there are nine of them. 9 falling edges that trigger either device to change the state of the data line, and 9 rising edges where they both sample it.

Comment: This is a new slave for me.  It is AMS AS3955 NFC chip.

Comment: I believe the pulses are counted, not the times it goes low.  First time it goes low is part of start condition.  See page 10, Fig 6. https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf

Comment: Two general suggestions for this type of problem:  1) find another slave which works and compare or 2) Temporarily disable the I2C engine and bit-bang the pins (preferably with someone's already proven code) in GPIO mode to experiment

Comment: I second the idea of comparing this to working I2C slave. Also you should try that twice, sending wrong address the second time. The traces of both transactions will be very helpful. Note that AS3955 has some crazy power schemes, where chip behavior is different in RF field etc. Part of the I2C address is programmable in EEPROM, silent mode disables IO, SS connection is required for I2C and the chip can even be permanently killed. All of the above requires investigation.

Comment: As @Maple commented way below, **"It looks more like the library does not know what to do with NACK."** I would second this opinion. I2C transactions are usually much longer, with extra bytes, and with clock stretching. There is no reason to expect STOP right after a single address phase.

Answer (score 3):

**Turns out my I2C slave doesn't support I2C.**

The AMS AS3955 is configured as a SPI or I2C device at factory time.  My device is a SPI one and I didn't notice.

Thanks for the discussions!

Comment: ROFL You sure got us jumping through the hoops

Answer (score 1):

> The slave drives SDA low at the end to ACK the transaction.

I don't see this. The SDA line should not go up at all. The slave reads incoming data on the **rising edge** of the clock. So, when 8th clock goes up slave *already* knows if this was the right address, so it pulls SDA down almost immediately after SCL goes down.

**Make sure the address is right.**

> Further more, the slave keeps SDA low since their isn't a 9th clock pulse, and my I2C peripheral gets stuck trying to finish the stop condition.

How do you know it is the slave that keeps line low? It is quite possible your reliable library does not handle NACK properly.

Comment: btw, slaves don't read data on the rising edge (as it can change any time SCL is low, and may not have settled when SCL rises). They read it on the falling edge.

Comment: @HenryCrun What a load of baloney! Slaves **cannot possibly know when falling edge comes in**. Technically they read SDA during high state of SCL, but the reading is triggered by rising edge, and that is exactly what is called "reading on rising edge". Learn the basics before giving advice.

Comment: "Baloney" is not a technical argument. Quote from the specification. https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf#page=50 fig 38 shows the timing diagram. `" A device must internally provide a hold time of at least 300 ns for the SDA signal (with respect to the VIH(min) of the SCL signal) to bridge the undefined region of the falling edge of SCL"' gives you a clear indication that data is (usually) captured on the falling edge. As Tsu:hd is only 250ns, and rise times can be >1us, clocking on the rising edge would leave a chip exposed to asymmetric rise times between SCL and SDA.

Comment: `"Slaves cannot possibly know when falling edge comes in."` I thought watching SCL would let them see the falling edge?

Comment: `"So, when 8th clock goes up slave already knows if this was the right address, so it pulls SDA down almost immediately."` is also incorrect. Neither slave or master is allowed to change the SDA state while SCL is high. (in fact address match could be done before falling edge of clock 7, and latched by fall of clk7, but is probably done after fall of C7 and latched by fall of C8)

Comment: I agree with your last statement. Slave cannot start ACK before clock goes down. I'll correct the answer. Note that address is not enough for slaves with R/O or W/O functionality, they need direction bit too.

Comment: Regarding the rest of it, you quoting the footnote and ignoring the word "internally" or the parameter itself, tHD;DAT, which for I2C is ZERO. Meaning, the transmitting side (i.e. "externally") can _change SDA at the same time it draws SCL low._ This is exactly what creates that "undefined region". On the other hand tSU;DAT is 50 ns even for fast mode. Meaning, by the time clock begins to rise the data _must be already set_. There is no Tsu:hd in specification, setup time and hold time are different things.

Comment: Sampling SDA on falling edge does not make any sense, especially at higher clock rates. It creates all kinds of problems, see [this](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m839283.aspx) for example. On the other hand sampling on rising edge is perfectly safe, because SDA must be already set long before that.

Comment: Also note, that the same footnote for high-speed devices (page 52) clarifies tHD;DAT parameter: "A device must internally provide a data hold time to bridge the undefined part _between VIH and VIL of the falling edge of the SCLH signal_. An input circuit with a threshold as low as possible for the falling edge of the SCLH signal _minimizes this hold time._". This whole thing is about allowing SDA line change as soon as possible (exactly because transmitter cannot do it while SCL is high, as you pointed out yourself).

Comment: That was someones random supposition. As I said show me where NXP support you. ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001795E.pdf#page=350 Fig30-29, SCL trace is clearly annotated `"data shifted in on falling edge of clk"`

Comment: You are looking at _master_ timing. Of course master can do this on _it's own_ clock signal because it takes time to propagate it to the slave. But this question deals with transmitting to slave. Look at any I2C scope traces (including this question btw) and you'll see SDA changing right at the falling edge of the clock, at the same time clock rising right in the middle of stable SDA state. You tell me when it is right time to sample it.

Comment: Fig29-14 Slave data is available on the falling edge. Just like the master which explicitly states it clocks on falling edge.

Comment: Maybe that is the reason I see so many posts on PICs failing to communicate with other Microchip own I2C devices. Anyway, once again: the tHD;DAT is defined from VIL on the falling SCL slope to the first threshold on SDA change. There is only one reason for this, the one you've given yourself: transmitter is not allowed to change SDA until SCL is low. And the specification clearly says min tHD;DAT = 0. This can happen _even before_ SCL reaches its lowest value! That is why NXP footnote talks about low threshold - make sure all reseivers get 0 on SCL, then change SDA as fast as possible.

Comment: They do not say change SDA as fast as possible at all. You have Tvd = 3.5us to change the data. If data was latched on rising edge then there would be no purpose in the 300ns internal hold. The data would remain unused.

Comment: Yes, tVD defines absolute longest time when the data must be ready. And you can see how it shrinks with the raise of bitrate. The devices must strive to minimize tHD, not merely fit into tVD constraint, for more reliable communication. This especially true for bit banging.

Comment: Anyway, I propose to agree to disagree for now. If (as I suspect) the OP simply got slave address wrong and the library failed to deal with NACK then this whole discussion becomes irrelevant.

Comment: SDA is held low at the end.  This is by the slave.  I'm suspecting the master clock'd in a NACK and immediately tries to do stop condition instead of finishing ninth clock cycle.  So there's this deadlock condition where the master can't do a stop (slave hold SDA low) and slave won't stop "ACK'ing" (ninth clock pulse doesn't finish).

Comment: @ConorPatrick Stop condition is low-to-high SCL transition while SDA is low. And if SDA is low already nothing prevents master from bringing clock down and up again. From your screenshot master not even tries to do this. It looks more like the library does not know what to do with NACK. You are sending address 0x50. Are you sure the lower 3 bits haven't been overridden in EEPROM?

Answer (score -1):

You are only showing 8 clock pulses for data, and is not showing the 9th ACK clock pulse falling edge.

The SDA should not be falling at the same time as SCL rises. It should have settled low within a couple of us of SCL falling, and before SCL rises. The master should be outputting the 9th clock falling edge and sampling SDA just before/at the falling edge.

I suspect your slave is not acking (address is wrong) as SDA stays high, and your library is aborting and forcing SDA low perhaps.

If this is a HW master, maybe it isn't set for I2C i.e. it's doing 8 clocks not 9. (as it is in SPI mode)

If it is a bit bash master, then you should be sampling SDA just before you make SCL fall (which your aren't doing), and definitely a couple of us after the rising edge.

Have a look at this [app note](https://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/I2C_Clock_Stretch_Probe.pdf#page=2) I wrote, that shows you how to see which chip (master or slave) is pulling the pin down. It talks about SCL, but will work the same for SDA

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZFeMY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BTW, from experience, manufacturers libraries are seldom fully functional or adequately debugged.

Comment: I think this circuit might make the logic low voltage levels too high for reliable operation. The maximum \$V_{OL}\$ for a standard device is 0.4V so you're really talking about a logic low voltage of about 1.1V. I would suggest using Schottky diodes instead.

Comment: Nah, VIL is what counts (0.3VDD = 1.5V) . It works fine. Read the appnote. There is a special case where you need schottkys: bus extenders and isolators. These have to use a threshold to determine driving direction. But if you have schottkys, they work fine or better also.

Comment: You are assuming that \$V_{DD}\$ is 5V...that's a pretty old-fashioned microcontroller. If by "appnote" you mean NXP UM10204 then I have read it. And you may be meeting the \$V_{IL}\$ but you have sacrificed a lot of the noise margin. At least we agree that Schottky diodes would work better.

Comment: Elliot, this is a simple test jig for someone to work out which chip is driving. Its not going to mars. Its not been nominated for a nobel prize, and its not running in liquid nitrogen or helping Comrade Kim land on the Sun at night. In the scope traces (you looked right?) the voltage is 0.7V with real chips. It works OK on earth, when I don't have to wear socks. Maybe not on mars.

Comment: My concern is that someone who doesn't know better will try to use this circuit to debug a system running at, say, 3.0V (on Earth, at room temperature, with socks on) and will end up running around in circles when nothing works at all. Yes, you were able to make it work at 5V with a certain set of devices, I see that. I just echoed information that was in your own appnote, in case the reader didn't click through.

Comment: At 0.7V , well yes it will still work just fine at 3.0V. In fact it will work for SMBus at 2.5V. As an aside, I first built it with schottkys. But it worked better i.e. it was clearer to see on a scope, with a bigger burden voltage. So I changed to 1n4148s.

Comment: Actually, SDA is held low at the end.  I haven't tested it with a circuit like you suggest, but that's a good idea.  I'm relatively confident it is the slave, because disconnecting the slave shows normal behavior.  Also the master gets stuck trying to finish stop condition but can't, because slave is holding SDA low.  Also there is no 9th clock pulse, I suspect because master clock'd in a NACK and just went straight to stop condition.

Comment: It will only **meet the I2C spec** at 3.0V if the \$V_{OL}\$ of the device is less than 0.2V, which is not required of a standard I2C device, or the forward voltage drop of the diode is less than 0.5V. The sum of the \$V_{OL}\$ and \$V_F\$ must be less than 0.3\$\times V_{DD}\$. The spec allows \$V_{OL}\$ to be as high as 0.4V.

Comment: @ConorPatrick I would try it, because what you have doesn't really make sense. However assuming it is the slave that is setting pulling SDA down late, it is possible that the slave is trying to clock stretch and the master is ignoring it, so also checking the SCL would eliminate that.

Comment: @ConorPatrick Changing the clock rate to longer would also eliminate the case where your slave is just coincidentally pulling SDA low at the same time SCL goes high. Seems a bit unlikely, but looking closely at the trace, SDA falling appears to happen while SCL rises, not following and caused by SCL rising